# One of the button created in android is moving to another activity while the other is not moving

Tags: android, button

This is the program.java code, please i dont know where the error is? Help me it is my schoolproject. Andoid Studio - I created two button on the activity named program but the button with id Full time is not moving to the second activity but the button with id parttime is moving.

```
package project.yctmobile.com.ycttutors;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Program extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_program);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fulltime);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.parttime);


        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Program.this, fulli.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                new Intent(Program.this, part.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the programactivity.xml

Comment: Check my answer below! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an obvious error (no offence intended) in your code. You declare an `Button button` in this line `Button button;` However when you assign the Button with your id you are overriding your button.

```
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fulltime);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.parttime);
```

So here your button first becomes the fulltime one and then is overrided by parttime.

Solution:

So to solve this issue add to Butons and assign them with different ids.
Hope it helps!

Like this

```
public class Program extends AppCompatActivity {

Button button1;
//This is for fulltime. (These are comments, wont be included in code so you can just leave it like that and compile :))
Button button2;
//This is for parttime
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_program);

    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fulltime);
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.parttime);


    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Program.this, part.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Program.this, fulli.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
}
}
```

So what you have done is use both your button id's in one button. Android cannot differentiate like that, so what I have done is put 2 different buttons for the 2 different id's and caught them in 2 different listeners and depending on which we call the required new activity.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you very much, I really appreciate your help, you save me a lot

Comment: @OdutolaAbisoye Sure, no problem. If it worked hit the check mark thus marking my answer as correct for reference for future readers! :)